# Configuring MassTransit's Ninject bindings after initialisation

Tags: c#, ninject, masstransit

I want to configure MassTransit at one point in my code (using WebActivator) and configure the message handlers in another (a Ninject module).  Is there a way I can achieve this?  The documentation [here](http://masstransit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration/containers.html) shows how to perform what I need in one step, but to do anyhting else, it looks like I need to get an instance of a `ServiceBusConfigurator`, which doesn't seem to be available from the preexisting `IServiceBus`

Answer (score 0):

Configuration and Creation of the `IServiceBus` cannot be separated.
That means, the only option you have is to gather the configuration information some *more* time before creating the bus.

As the [doc you linked](http://masstransit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration/containers.html) states, the meta data information made available by ninject is not sufficient to create the subscriptions. This basically means that you've got to create your own metadata model. Let's make an example, which can be used with single registrations but also with convention based registrations:

*Hint: You should treat the following code snippets as psuedo code as i've written them from memory. It's highly likely that it won't compile*.

### Metadata Model

```
public class SubscriptionMetadata
{
    public SubscriptionMetadata(Type consumer)
    {
        if(!typeof(IConsumer).IsAssignableFrom(consumer))
        {
            string message = string.Format(
                "{0} does not implement {1}",
                typeof(IConsumer).Name,
                consumer.Name);
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("consumer", message);
        }

        this.ConsumerType = consumer;
    }

    public Type ConsumerType { get; private set; }
}
```

### Registration of Metadata

Now this can be used like this in a Ninject module:

```
Bind<SubscriptionMetadata>()
   .ToConstant(new SubscriptionMetadata(typeof(FooConsumer));
```

If you're going to use it a lot i'd recommend writing an extension method:

```
public static class SubscriptionBindingExtensions
{
    public static void BindConsumer<T>(this IBindingRoot bindingRoot)
        where T : IConsumer
    {
        Bind<SubscriptionMetadata>()
          .ToConstant(new SubscriptionMetadata(typeof(T));
    }
}
```

and usage (@Module):

```
BindConsumer<FooConsumer>();
```

### `IServiceBus` creation

Now you would adapt the `IServiceBus` creation as follows:

```
var kernel = new StandardKernel();
// 2nd Step left out: load all IModule`s ..

var bus = ServiceBusFactory.New(sbc =>
{
    //other configuration options

    foreach(var metadata in kernel.GetAll<SubscriptionMetadata>())
    {
        sbc.Subscribe(subs =>
        {
            subs.Consumer(metadata.ConsumerType, kernel)
        });
    }
});
```

### Convention based binding of Consumers

It can also be used in conjunction with [conventions](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.conventions) by leveraging the [`IBindingCreator`](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Extensions.Conventions/blob/master/src/Ninject.Extensions.Conventions/BindingBuilder/IBindingCreator.cs) interface. If you wish, i can post an example.